# How Do I Make Multiple Copies of a Javascript Object in and Array and Edit Those Objects Separately

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to make an array of objects, some being copies of other objects.  I need to be able to modify those objects individually later on though.
Here is what I am doing at the moment...

```
var fruit = [
{ type="banana", copies="3" },
{ type="apple", copies="2" },
]
```

Later I take all that fruit and put it in a basket.

```
for (i=0; i < fruit.length; i++){
    for(x=0; x < fruit[i].copies; x++){
        basket.push(fruit[i]);}}
```

At this point I can get a list of all the fruit, the basket length is 5 and everything seems great.  Later in the code when I try to add properties to a single piece of fruit...

```
basket[2].status='rotten';
```

...every banana is then rotten and not just the 3rd one.  The apples are all the same as before with an undefined status.

I am very new to Javascript, so I apologize if this is something that is normally common knowledge.  Everything I have Googled hasn't been what I was looking for and trying to learn from what I did find hasn't helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are copying the reference to the fruit[i] in basket and not the cloning it. You have to clone it using something like this

```
var fruitToBePushed = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(fruit[i]));
```

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1L9vdw60/)

Complete Code:

```
var fruit = [
    { type:"banana", copies:"3" },
    { type:"apple", copies:"2" },
];
 var basket=[];
 for (var i=0; i < fruit.length; i++){
    for(var x=0; x < fruit[i].copies; x++){
        var fruitToBePushed = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(fruit[i]));
        basket.push(fruitToBePushed);}}
 basket[2].status='rotten';
 console.log(basket);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to achieve your goal: [Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```
var a=[1,2,3];
var b=a;
var c=a.slice();

a[1]=99;
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sm2n4zb2/) to play with.

Offtopic:

Since you are a novice to JS, I would recommend to have a look at [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). This will help you, writing more concise code.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I'll read through the links you gave me and incorporate them somewhere in this project.  The main point of this project is to learn JS.